# Neo4j: how to join multiple relations into a summarized one?

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have a graph where there are many relations between some of the nodes, which makes browsing these graphs difficult. Is it possible to replace such multiple relations with a single "aggregated" one, possible of another type?

Ideally, I would like to join just those relations where there are more than 10 relations between a node pain - but anything will help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can do something like:

```
// Match the pattern
MATCH (a:Node)-[t:REL_TYPE]->(b:Node)
// pass to the next context nodes a, b, list of t 
// where number of relations between a and b is greater than 10
WITH a, b, collect(t) AS ts, count(t) AS count
WHERE count > 10
// create new relation between a and b nodes
CREATE (a)-[:OTHER_REL_TYPE]->(b)
// pass list of old relations to the next context
WITH ts
// unwind & delete old relations
UNWIND (ts) AS t
DELETE t
RETURN *
```

Comment: Wow, thank you! This is exactly what I was looking for (and much more)!

Comment: @johndodo oh you are welcome! :) But what you mean with "makes browsing these graphs difficult"? Can you explain a bit more?

Comment: Sure... I have _many_ relations between some of the nodes, so when I visualize them Firefox sometimes crashes (usually when I move nodes closer to the edge of browser window). Chromium isn't crashing, but it is much slower and freezes for a few seconds every now and then.